# Bash propagate variables when called with -c

Tags: bash

I'm using ZSH.
Why does the last command not output anything?

```
$ cat create_foo.sh 
foo=bar

$ source create_foo.sh && echo $foo
bar

$ unset foo

$ bash -c "source create_foo.sh && echo $foo"
```

From the last command I don't get any output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$foo` is getting substituted with an empty string in the double quotes.

You need to either use single quotes or escape the `$` sign:

```
$ bash -c 'source create_foo.sh && echo $foo'
bar

$ bash -c "source create_foo.sh && echo \$foo"
bar
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's it. Here's an answer that explains the difference between single quotes and double quotes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/2285820